# Can I apply full-sized brick to an interior wall if shared with a fireplace?

Tags: walls, brick, interior

Similar to a previous post, I don't want to use veneer, I want to use real brick. The wall is in my living room and it includes a wood-burning fireplace. The existing wall has what seems like faux stone veneer (haven't demo'd to confirm), floor-to-ceiling and wall-to-wall.

Existing stone similar to this style (but mine is floor to ceiling wall to wall) 
http://www.hotelpicodaurze.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Custom-Wall-Coverings.jpg

If full sized brick walls require proper concrete footings to support the massive amount of weight, then perhaps my existing concrete footings are sufficient since I have a chimney shared with that wall?  I assume the chimney was constructed at the same time as the house.

Comment: Fireplace is not built on top of floor it is built from ground under house

Answer (score 1):

The chimney is not supported by the floor system, it is built from the ground up with a foundation of concrete under it.

Full 4” brick weigh 40 pounds per square foot so a wall that is 9’ tall and 15’ long would add 5400 lbs to the floor system.

I would want an engineer to approve the area in question to be certain that it can support this added weight with out compromising the integrity of the structure.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I will consult with an engineer.  The wall in question is 8' tall and 14' long so pretty close to your estimate.  I will report back with what I learn.

Comment: 40 psf is a little strong...maybe 30 psf, but +1 for illustrating the magnitude of such a wall.